# Does Xamarin offer a native number picker that I can use with Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have used the standard picker which comes up with a box on the screen and allows me to select from a list.

But is there a native Xamarin picker that can be used just to pick numbers and populate a binder number?  Something like I see on applications where a telephone keypad type thing displays with the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 and a backspace. This seems like a common kind of control for when a user wants to enter a number or dollar amount.

I look in the sample apps but could not find any example of this. If there is not one then is the only way to implement a series of numbers in a list ?

Comment: There is a spinner control, as well as a generic Picker control.  I'm not sure what exactly you have in mind?

Comment: I have an application where the user needs to be able to populate a time in seconds.  I am not familiar with the spinner but is the generic picker the one where you can provide an ItemSource list for it and it has a Done button on the top right?

Comment: Just try to do it yourself lol

Comment: It's Stepper, not Spinner.  All the built in controls are shown here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/views/

Comment: The kind of control I am interested in is one that when I click on an input field it opens up a box on the bottom of the screen with a number pad 1,2,3,4 ... 9 etc.  Similar thing to a telephone dialer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The kind of control I am interested in is one that when I click on an input field it opens up a box on the bottom of the screen with a number pad

Use an [Entry](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry/) with the Keyboard property set to Numeric

```xml
<Entry Keyboard="Numeric" />
```

Comment: But then i can copy-paste text into it still, can't I?